# JSONDecodeError when trying to make request counter with Django

Tags: python, json, django, exception, json-deserialization

So I wanted to make a "reqcount" thing in my django project using a JSON file but when I run it I get this error:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/testing/reqcount/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.8.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'testing']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\.virtualenvs\WEBSITE-PTmWcCQQ\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\chris\.virtualenvs\WEBSITE-PTmWcCQQ\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Desktop\WEBSITE\testing\views.py", line 17, in req_count
    return HttpResponse(json.load(f))
  File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /testing/reqcount/
Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

This is my views.py code (ignore the "hello" function):

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')


def req_count(request):
    # TODO: Update the amount of requests the "reqcount" url has gotten, then return it
    with open('..\\data.json', 'w+') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        data['views']['reqcount']['reqs'] += 1
        json.dump(data)

        return HttpResponse(data['views']['reqcount']['reqs'])
```

NOTES:

- I am using Windows 10
- I am using Python 3.8
- I am using pipenv 2021.5.29
- I am using Django 3.2.6
- I do not get any errors upon starting my web server by running "py manage.py runserver"

EDIT:
I changed my code to:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
import json

def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')

def req_count(request):
    with open('data.json', "a+") as f:
        data = json.loads(f.read())

    with open('data.json', "w+") as f:
        data['views']['reqcount']['reqs'] += 1
        f.write(json.dumps(data))

    return HttpResponse(data['views']['reqcount']['reqs'])
```

and my error changed to:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/testing/reqcount/

Django Version: 3.2.6
Python Version: 3.8.6
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'testing']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\chris\.virtualenvs\WEBSITE-PTmWcCQQ\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\chris\.virtualenvs\WEBSITE-PTmWcCQQ\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\chris\Desktop\WEBSITE\testing\views.py", line 10, in req_count
    data = json.loads(f.read())
  File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\json\__init__.py", line 357, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\users\chris\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /testing/reqcount/
Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: According to the given traceback, the error is get triggered by the `return HttpResponse(json.load(f))` statement and that couldn't found in the given error snippet

Comment: For that style of file pathname on Windows, you'll be needing a raw string. Also, there's nothing in your code to suggest that 'w+' is an appropriate mode for opening the file as you only ever read from it

Comment: @DarkKnight what about ```json.dump(data)```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't comment to ask for more info because of low reputation points( less than 50)

I think the issue is that if your JSON file is empty and try to read, you will get a `JSONDecodeError` but not if there is valid JSON data in the file. With `w+`, you get the same error even if the file has valid JSON data because it clears the file(or rather overwrite the file) contents before any action is performed.

The solution I can think of is creating 2 functions for reading and updating the `reqs` attribute.

Assuming the JSON file is not empty, you might have something like this:

**file.json**

```
{
    "views": {
        "reqcount": {
            "reqs": 1    
        }
    }
}
```

```
def read_json_file(filename):
    """
    read data from json file 
    return: dict
    """
    with open(filename, "a+") as file:  # use a+ to deal with the case where the file does not exist
        data = json.load(file)
        return data


def update_json_file(filename, data):
    """ update the json file by changing the 'reqs` count """
    with open(filename, "w+") as file:
        data['views']['reqcount']['reqs'] += 1
        file.write(json.dumps(data))
        return data
```

Then you can call these functions inside the view  **e.g**

```
def req_count(request):
    # TODO: Update the amount of requests the "reqcount" url has gotten, then return it
    data = read_json_file("file.json")
    updated_data = update_json_file("file.json", data)

    return HttpResponse(updated_data['views']['reqcount']['reqs'])
```

So everytime the view is called, the count will update.

Comment: the JSON file is not empty. also i dont have access to my computer so give me around 12 hours then will accept your answer if it works

Comment: also the JSON file is completely unchanged after testing the view

Comment: This answer did not work. I did find out that "..\\data.json" was part of the problem. I replaced all of those paths with "json.data" which worked when I ran ```print(f.read())```, but the issue is still not fixed